# Move cursor to next line having it aligned to last char of previous line

Tags: c#, string-formatting

`\f` is an escape char in Java, which moves the cursor into next line and makes the first character starting off the right of current line last character ([ref](https://www.journaldev.com/28692/java-printf-method))

```
System.out.printf("%s\f%s!%n","Hello","World!");
Hello
     World!!
```

I wonder how is it possible to achieve that in c#?

Answer (score 1):

It is `\v` – Vertical quote

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello\vWorld");
```

Similar behaviour can be achieved with `.SetCursorPosition` method.

```
Console.Write("Hello");
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop + 1);
Console.WriteLine("World!");

// Output:
// Hello
//      World!
```

Or by updating `.CursorTop` value

```
Console.Write("Hello");
Console.CursorTop++;
Console.WriteLine("World!");

// Output:
// Hello
//      World!
```